# Changing font / label size with animation in swift

Tags: animation, swift, resize, label

Im after come code to increase the size of my label when the game over code is run.... here is what i have at the moment

```
if gameOver == 0 {
            movingObjects.speed = 0
            gameOver = 1
            movingObjects.removeAllChildren()// Remove all enemies
            gameOverLabel.fontSize = 43
            gameOverLabel.text = "Tap to retry!"
            gameOverLabel.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)*1.5)
            labelHolder.addChild(gameOverLabel)
            gameOverLabel.zPosition = 9



            var pauseScore = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.4)
            var moveScore = SKAction.moveToY(CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)*1.2, duration: 0.8)
            var resizeScore = SKAction.runBlock({
            self.scoreLabel.fontSize = 150
            })
            var scoreEndSequence = SKAction.sequence([pauseScore, moveScore, resizeScore])
            scoreLabel.runAction(scoreEndSequence)


            if (UInt(score) > UInt(hScore as NSNumber)) {
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(score, forKey: "highscore")
                println("Highscore Saved")
            } else {
                println("Highscore Not Saved")
            }
```

I would like the scoreLabel to also get bigger... now what i have now does do it but it just jumps up to 150 i would like it to animate up

Answer (score 1):

It seems the property `fontSize` is not animatable.
To fix it, change your holder into a view object

Comment: Ah i see, any ideas of how to do this? Reasonably new to coding and haven't learnt that part yet

Comment: I'm afraid you have to learn about UIKit and if you want to go further, learn Core Animation

Answer (score 0):

You can animate the node size like this:

```
var grow = SKAction.scaleTo(10, duration: 0.5)
```

But if you do this with a SKLabelNode the text will look bad if it gets too big. The text with not rendered again when the node size changes.